# opencv mouse handling on windows form application vc++

Tags: .net, opencv, visual-c++

I am unable to perform opencv mouse handling in vc++ windows form application. I am getting following error

Error   29  error C3867: 'touch_gui_trial1::Form1::mouseHandler': function call missing argument list; use '&touch_gui_trial1::Form1::mouseHandler' to create a pointer to member   c:\users\mridul\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\touch_gui_trial1\Form1.h  104 1   touch_gui_trial1

the code snippet is as follows

```
            public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {
    public:

    int i,cntr2,count,camno,cntr,ch,prev,flag_camno,hand_thresh_area;
    static int handthresharea=0,flagroi=0,drag; 
    static Point sz,point;

            void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
    {
        IplImage* img0;

        img0=(IplImage *)param;
            /* user press left button */
        if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
        {
            point = Point(x, y);
            drag  = 1;
        }

        /* user drag the mouse */
        if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
        {
            img1 = cvCloneImage (img0);

            cvRectangle(
                img1,
                point,
                cvPoint(x, y),
                CV_RGB(255, 0, 0),
                1, 8, 0
            );

                        cvShowImage("Image taken", img1);
        }

        /* user release left button */
        if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
        {
            img1 = cvCloneImage(img0);

            cvSetImageROI(img1,cvRect(point.x,point.y,x - point.x,y - point.y));
            sz.x=x - point.x;
            sz.y=y - point.y;
            //cvNot(img1, img1);    // or do whatever with the ROI

            //cvResetImageROI(img1);
            cvNamedWindow("the roi",1); cvShowImage("the roi", img1);
            flagroi=1;
            drag = 0;
        }

        /* user click right button: reset all */
        if (event == CV_EVENT_RBUTTONUP)
        {
            //cvShowImage("Image taken", img0);
            drag = 0;
        }
    }
    int select_roi()
    {
        CvCapture *frame;
        IplImage* img0;
        IplImage* img1;

        frame=cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
        cvNamedWindow( "ROI Selection", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        if ( !frame ) 
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
            getchar();
            return -1;
        }
        img0= cvQueryFrame(frame);
        cvShowImage("ROI Selection", img0);
        cvSetMouseCallback("ROI Selection", ::mouseHandler, img0);
                    **//error is in the above line**

        return 0;
    }
```

// rest is the GUi part from where the select roi is called.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your code:

- It seems you have 2 `mouseHandler()` methods with the exact same signature;
- When using methods as callbacks, you need to make sure they are `static` methods:

  ```
  static void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) { ... }
  ```

and when you specify your callback to `cvSetMouseCallback()` you should do it like this:

```
cvSetMouseCallback("ROI Selection", &Form1::mouseHandler, img0);
```

Comment: when i tried making it static i get error like this :-----------Error 28 error C2664: 'cvSetMouseCallback' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__clrcall touch_gui_trial1::Form1::* )(int,int,int,int,void *)' to 'CvMouseCallback' c:\users\mridul\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\touch_gui_trial1\Form1.h 104 1 touch_gui_trial1

Comment: That happens when you don't share the full source code of your application. *Form1* seems to be an object inside another class, which is something you didn't show in your code. You have a few options here, one of them is simply move the callback method from `Form1` to `touch_gui_trial1`, and then pass it to `cvSetMouseBacllback()` as `&touch_gui_trial1::mousehandler`. From now on, I can only help you if you share a minimal application that reproduces the problem you are facing. I'm retiring my crystal ball.

Comment: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12351672/touch_gui_trial1.rar) it is the link to my project

Comment: Meanwhile, one of your other questions has been successfully answered. I suggest you accept the answer that solved it.

Comment: I don't have VS2010 installed in this computer, only 2008. Will take a look at that later.

Comment: 1st issues was copying it wrongly to stackoverflow....  sry for that... thanks for ur help

Comment: I had many errors compiling your project and I'm giving up on this thread. Example: `Form1.h(52): error C2065: 'img1' : undeclared identifier`. Come back when you have a minimal example to reproduce the problem you are facing.